# Block POST requests based on referer header using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website with a lot of [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) issues and fixing them using CSRF token will take a lot of work.
So , my question is : can I block POST requests based on referer header using .htaccess ? 
For example this request should be allowed:

```
POST http://mywebsite.com/password
REFERER: http://mywebsite.com/

pass=xxxx
```

but this one should be blocked.

```
POST http://mywebsite.com/password
REFERER: http://evil.com/

pass=xxxx
```

also , and how to block POST requests with no REFERER header ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to invest effort in something you know yourself will not be reliable. Why not fix the issue itself instead, which is what you have to do anyway? The only alternative is to take that site offline _now_.

Comment: @arkascha for some reasons I can't take the website down. Also , this will be a temporarily fix until to prevent such attacks until I fix them using CSRF tokens.
 > _The only alternative is to take that site offline now._...
 so do you think the htaccess fix can't be done ? 
thanks

Comment: You certainly can block _some_ requests. but that will never be reliable, since the criteria you name can be easily forged. So what's the point? You really think Mr. Bad Guy will _not_ forge the referrer if you ask him not to in a friendly way?

Comment: @arkascha , Actually , no there is no way for Mr. Bad Guy to change the referrer header in a request , therefore he can't achieve a CSRF attack. the htaccess fix will work as expected and will prevent hackers/spammers from hacking users with those CSRF issues , however I will do the CSRF tokens fix since it's the best way to prevent such attacks . but for now I really in need to do the quick htaccess fix.

Comment: `curl --referer forgedRefererValue http://www.your.website.com` it's **that** easy to set a referer header

Comment: @AlexAndrei , please read more about CSRF!! 
the point here , is that an attacker can trick a user to visit a specially crafted HTML page that will submit a form with the method "POST" for example to change the user's password to a website where the user is already authenticated. and in this case , using HTML and JavaScript you can't set a `forgedRefererValue` because it violates The same origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RewriteCond` directive with conditions for `REQUEST_METHOD` and `HTTP_REFERER`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ # <- remove this line
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This will send a `403 Forbidden` to all `POST` requests with an empty referer or not equal to `http://www.yourdomain.com/anything`

Examples

```
$ curl -vvv --data something --referer http://www.yourdomain.com/something http://yourdomain.com/
200 OK

$ curl -vvv --data something --referer http://evildomain.com http://yourdomain.com/something-else
403 Forbidden

$ curl -vvv --data something --referer http://yourdomain.com http://yourdomain.com/something-else
403 Forbidden

$ curl -vvv --data something http://yourdomain.com/something-else
403 Forbidden
```

Comment: I have checked again , but looks like that only works if the referer is empty and it doesn't work when it's set for example to `http://evil.com`.

Comment: remove line with the empty referer condition, it will be met by `!=yourdomain`

Comment: Thank you it works now when the referer is not mydomain.com , however , it only works for requests on www.mydomain.com , but for www.mydomain.com/something , it doesn't Work. Sorry for that , but I am not that good with htaccess , can you please tell me what could be done wrong in this case , thanks ?

Comment: what do mean when you say it works or it doesn't work? works = the request is successfully blocked? check any other rewrite rules you may have

Comment: With it works I mean that the request gets blocked and I get a 403 error. With it doesn't work I mean that the request doesn't get blocked and I get a 200 response.

Comment: Thanks it works fine on all the website now. You were right , I had another rewrite rule that prevented it from working with other site paths. 
Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to implement the CSRF token later on :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general recipe you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=http://mywebsite.com/
# XXX: /? for htaccess-vs-vhost portability
RewriteRule ^/?password - [F]
```